# Save() method does not save my form to database

Tags: django, forms, django-models

Coding a simple form to add articles to website. Failed to add any information from form to database.

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
    anons = models.CharField('announcement', max_length=250)
    full_text = models.TextField('Article') 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'news'
```

my forms.py

```
from .models import Articles
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Textarea


class ArticlesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Articles
        fields = ['title', 'anons', 'full_text']

        widgets = {
            'title': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Header'
            }),
            'anons': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Announcement'
            }),
            'full_text': Textarea(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Text'
            }),
        }
```

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Articles
from .forms import ArticlesForm

def news(request):
    news = Articles.objects.all() #[:2] - срез записей
    return render(request, 'news_templates/news.html', {'news': news})

def create(request):
    
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticlesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
            return redirect('./')
        else:
            error = "Wrong format"


    form = ArticlesForm()
    
    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error
    }

    return render(request, 'news_templates/create.html', data)
```

template for page

```
{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Create article
{% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
    <main class="features">
        <h1>Add an article</h1>
        <form method='post'>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.title }}<br>
            {{ form.anons }}<br>
            {{ form.full_text }}<br>
            <button class='btn btn-success' type='submit'>Add article</button>
            <span> {{ error }} </span>
        </form>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Made makemigrations and migrate. I can add any article via admin panel. Server responds correctly to post:

```
[09/Aug/2023 18:10:10] "GET /news/create HTTP/1.1" 200 2146
[09/Aug/2023 18:16:24] "POST /news/create HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[09/Aug/2023 18:16:24] "GET /news/ HTTP/1.1" 200 198
```

But it doesn't appear in my database. Don't mind where is the problem.

Comment: it is important to add the `action` in the form.

Comment: it should be `form.save()` not `form.save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to actually call the **`save()`** method:

```py
def create(request):
    
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticlesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # <-------
            return redirect('./')
```

Comment: Lol, maximum level of errors due to inattention. Thx!